# Text wraps underneath an Ordered List with a circle padding

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**UPDATE:**
I added two spans inside a div inside the li item. So far I almost got the list to align properly, but now the entire row of text shifts to the next line over instead of the words wrapping.

Check out my [New Fiddle for more info](https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/8whb3uy3/6/)

[image]

**ORIGINAL ISSUE:**
I've created an ordered list with a border radius of a circle, padding and background color, but no matter what I try the text wraps underneath the ordered list number.

Issue: **How can I prevent the text from wrapping underneath the ordered list number inside the circle?**

[image]

Here's my [Fiddle of the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/godsnake/8whb3uy3/5/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="child">
<div class="child2">

<h3 class="title">
ddddddddd dddddddddd ddddddddd ddddddddddddddddd
</h3>
<ol class="circlegroup">
<li>1 I want to center the parent but align this to the left ddddddddddd dddddd dddddd dddd dddddd</li>
<li>2 I want to center the parent but align this to the left ddddddddddd dddddd dddddd dddd dddddd</li>
<li>3 I want to center the parent but align this to the left ddddddddddd dddddd dddddd dddd dd dddd</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {min-height:100%!important; height:100%!important;}

html {min-height:100%!important; height:100%!important;}

.parent {background:yellow; width:100%; height:100%;  display: table;
}

.child {background:red; width:70%;  display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;}

    .child2 {background:#fff; width:100%; display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;}

    .circlegroup {  }

 .circlegroup li {
   list-style:none;
  width:auto; margin-left:10%;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  word-wrap: break-word;

  margin-bottom:40px;
}

.title {margin-left:10%;}


ol { list-style: none; padding-left: 10px; text-indent:0px; margin-left:5px; }

ol li {color:#666; }

ol li:first-letter {color:#fff; background:#333; border-radius:50%; border: 5px solid #333;font-size:4vw;   vertical-align:middle;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);padding-left:2%; padding-right:2%; padding-top:0%; padding-bottom:0%; font-weight:bold; margin-right:1vw; height:100%;  list-style-position:outside;}


ol li 
{ list-style-position:outside;

}
```

Comment: That's not how to style list items manually. You should use pseudo elements and counters.

Comment: Can you provide an example or updated fiddle? I've tried ol li { list-style-position:outside;} and I've also tried text-indent: -1em; as well as other solutions using the :before element with no success

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? I had to change quite a bit, particularly to get the circles around the digits right, because they weren't always circular in your example. Their shapes depended on the width of the window.
But now I'm not sure if you wanted the circles to be inside the borders or not.

```css
html, body {
  padding:0; margin:0;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
}

.parent {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  display: table;
}

.child {
  background: red;
  width: 70%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.child2 {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.title {
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.circlegroup {
  counter-reset:circle;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 10px;
  text-indent: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.circlegroup li {
  min-height: calc(7vw - 40px);
  list-style: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-left: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  color: #666;
  position:relative;
}

.circlegroup li:before {
  counter-increment: circle;
  content:counter(circle);
  color: #fff;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 4vw; line-height:1ch;
  box-sizing:content-box;
  width:1ch; height:1ch; padding:1ch;
  behavior: url(PIE.htc);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right: .25em;
  position:absolute; top:0; right:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container parent">

  <div class="child">
    <div class="child2">

      <h3 class="title">
ddddddddd dddddddddd ddddddddd ddddddddddddddddd
</h3>
      <ol class="circlegroup">
        <li>I want to center the parent but align this to the left ddddddddddd dddddd dddddd dddd dddddd</li>
        <li>I want to center the parent but align this to the left ddddddddddd dddddd dddddd dddd dddddd</li>
        <li>I want to center the parent but align this to the left ddddddddddd dddddd dddddd dddd dd dddd</li>
        <li>I want to center the parent but align this to the left ddddddddddd dddddd dddddd dddd dddddssddddddddddddddddddddd</li>
        <li>I want to center the parent but align this to the left ddddddddddd dddddd dddddd dddd dddddd</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That only works in the smaller screen size, but when you resize the screen the circles start to overlap. See the screenshot: i.is.cc/I7ypCR.png

Comment: That can easily be corrected. See edit. But I'm still not sure what you want exactly. You have provided only screenshots of how you _don't_ want it to look, not how it _should_ look.